# Realm object in object returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a realm object Activity that has as a number of variables including realm objects User, Profile and Board. Here is the declaration of the object

```
class RealmActivity: Object
{
    dynamic var user: RealmProfile?
    dynamic var noticeId = ""
    dynamic var notice: RealmNotice?
    dynamic var board: RealmBoard?
    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var date = Date()
    dynamic var text = ""
    dynamic var commentContent = ""
}
```

Here is the conversion from Class to Realm Object

```
func cacheActivity(activity: Activity) -> RealmActivity
{
    let realm = RealmActivity()

    if activity.user != nil {
        realm.user = cacheUser(user: activity.user!)
    }
    if activity.noticeId != nil {
        realm.noticeId = activity.noticeId!
    }
    if activity.notice != nil {
        realm.notice = cacheNotice(notice: activity.notice!)
    }
    if activity.board != nil {
        realm.board = cacheBoard(board: activity.board!, tag: "activity")
    }
    realm.type = activity.type!
    realm.date = activity.date!

    if activity.text != nil {
        realm.text = activity.text!
    }

    if activity.commentContent != nil {
        realm.commentContent = activity.commentContent!
    }

    return realm
}
```

And here is the method that caches all activities. 
I first get all the already cached objects and delete them. Then I get the updated list of activities and add them to realm

```
func cacheAllActivities()
{
    let realmCached = realm.objects(RealmActivity.self)

    let activities = SessionManager.sharedInstance.dashboard.activities
    var realmActivities = [RealmActivity]()

    if activities.count > 0 {
        try! realm.write()
        {
            realm.delete(realmCached)

            for activity in activities
            {
                let realmActivity = cacheActivity(activity: activity)
                self.realm.add(realmActivity)
                realmActivities.append(realmActivity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im using this object to persist push notifications as activities on the phone. 
When I write an object, the first time I go back to the app I manage to retrieve it with all its objects without a problem. When I close the app and retrieve it for a second time, my objects RealmProfile, RealmNotice and RealmBoard return nil when they should not be empty. The rest of the data is there, only the objects within an object are not returned. Again this happens when I retrieve the object more than once. After that its always nil. I don't rewrite the object after each restart. I have been on this for a few days, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I do, I write each object into Realm and convert each object separately to conform with Realm objects. I am able to write these objects in memory and retrieve them as variables of another object so that shouldn't be the problem as it seems to work. But after a few app restarts the object is returned with all its values intact except from the object variables which become nil.

Comment: When these properties become nil, did you check if the objects themselves are still in your Realm instance? Determining whether the objects themselves get deleted/are never stored or only if there relationship to RealmActivity gets deleted should help find the reason for this issue.

Comment: Yeah the objects are not deleted. I still get the correct amount of objects returned with only some of the properties there, so the objects are stored in my Realm instance and I manage to get each object returned intact the first time. After a few tries the object properties become nil

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening without more information. Please send a full Xcode project that reproduces the issue you're seeing, along with steps to reproduce to help@realm.io, and we'll happily investigate this for you.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?